# Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled: * Length 61: Column `y` * Length 10358: Column `x`

Tags: r, dplyr, r-plotly

I am trying to plot the coronavirus spread in India vs Rest of the world by using the below R code
I have corona_world as a dataframe and created daily_confirmed dataframe from it .I have eliminated all values of NA in variable column 'India' . But still the error says it does not have same length. I don't understand why it isn't working. Please help

Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled: * Length 61: Column y * Length 10358: Column x

```
daily_confirmed <- corona_world %>%
  dplyr::select(Confirmed) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(country = dplyr::if_else(corona_world$Country.Region == "India",
                                         "India",
                                         "Rest of the World")) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(corona_world$ObservationDate, country) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(total = sum(Confirmed, rm.na=TRUE)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = country, values_from = total)

daily_confirmed <- daily_confirmed[-c(1:8),]
daily_confirmed %>%
  plotly::plot_ly() %>%
  plotly::add_trace(x = ~ corona_world$ObservationDate,
                    y = ~ India,
                    type = "scatter",
                    mode = "lines+markers",
                    name = "India") %>%
  plotly::add_trace(x = ~ corona_world$ObservationDate,
                    y = ~ Rest of the World,
                    type = "scatter",
                    mode = "lines+markers",
                    name = "Rest of the World") %>%
  plotly::layout(title = "",
                 legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.9),
                 yaxis = list(title = "Number of New Cases"),
                 xaxis = list(title = "Date"),
                 hovermode = "compare",
                 margin = list(b = 10,
                               t = 10,
                               pad = 2
                 ))
```

The input is https://i.stack.imgur.com/R63v8.png

Answer (score 1):

Besides some typos in your code, the error is due to mapping `corona_world$ObservationDate` on `x`. You have to map `ObservationDate` from `daily_confirmed` on `x`. Also, when using var names with spaces like in "Rest of the World" you have to put the var name in backticks, like so: "y = ~ `Rest of the World`".

Try this. I checked on gapminder data, so it should work. BTW: I also revised your code to make it more concise:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)

daily_confirmed <- corona_world %>%
  #select(Confirmed) %>%
  mutate(country = dplyr::if_else(Country.Region == "India",
                                         "India",
                                         "Rest of the World")) %>%
  group_by(ObservationDate, country) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Confirmed, rm.na=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = country, values_from = total)

daily_confirmed <- daily_confirmed[-c(1:8),]
daily_confirmed %>%
  plotly::plot_ly() %>%
  plotly::add_trace(x = ~ ObservationDate,
                    y = ~ India,
                    type = "scatter",
                    mode = "lines+markers",
                    name = "India") %>%
  plotly::add_trace(x = ~ ObservationDate,
                    y = ~ `Rest of the World`,
                    type = "scatter",
                    mode = "lines+markers",
                    name = "Rest of the World") %>%
  plotly::layout(title = "",
                 legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.9),
                 yaxis = list(title = "Number of New Cases"),
                 xaxis = list(title = "Date"),
                 hovermode = "compare",
                 margin = list(b = 10,
                               t = 10,
                               pad = 2
                 ))
```